# Why won't my ball bounce off a block?

Tags: math, processing, collision, game-physics

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm checking which side the ball has hit and changing the x/y components appropriately but it just goes straight through the box. Any help? Thanks.

```
PVector p = new PVector(0, 0); //position
PVector v = new PVector(5, 10); //velocity

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  rect(250, 250, 200, 100);
  ellipse(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
  p.add(v);
  if (p.x < 0 || p.x > width) // ball hit sides of window
  {
    v.x = -v.x;
  }
  if (p.y < 0 || p.y > height) // ball hit top/bottom of window
  {
    v.y = -v.y;
  }
  if (p.x > 250 && p.x < 450 && p.y > 250 && p.y < 350) // ball is inside box
  {
    if (p.y - v.y <= 250 || p.y + v.y >= 350) // ball came from above/below
    {
      v.y = -v.y;
    } 
    if (p.x - v.x <= 250 || p.x + v.x >= 450) // ball came from sides
    {
      v.x = -v.x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Kind of hard to figure it out without seeing how it looks like or debugging it, but my guess is that it happens because you're checking whether the center of the ball is inside the box instead of its edges. That way it could be that the center is very close to the box not satisfying your condition but the rest of the ball seems to be inside it. Try to change the condition to `p.x + 20 >= 250 || p.x - 20 <= 450` etc

Comment: it still doesn't work :(

Comment: What did you change, and actually happens? is the ball completely inside the box? or only part of it?

Comment: It goes straight through the box. The code i pasted is the whole program by the way so you can run it and see what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initial set up is actually almost perfect. I only changed 2 things in the the third if statement (the if statement which handles the collision with the rectangle).

-Added/subtracted the width/height of the dot to the x/y of the dot. Because of this you will not just use the center of the dot for the collision detection but the whole dot.

-Changed > or < in >= <=, because you're working with increments of 5 and 10 it is almost certain that the dot has an X which is the same as either 250 or 450. Same for the Y.

Here is my version of the complete script, hope it helps!

```
PVector p = new PVector(0, 0); //position
PVector v = new PVector(5, 10); //velocity

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  rect(250, 250, 200, 100);
  ellipse(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
  p.add(v);
  if (p.x < 0 || p.x > width) // ball hit sides of window
  {
    v.x = -v.x;
  }
  if (p.y < 0 || p.y > height) // ball hit top/bottom of window
  {
    v.y = -v.y;
  }
  if (p.x + 10 >= 250 && p.x - 10 <= 450 && p.y + 10 >= 250 && p.y - 10 <= 350) // ball is inside box
  {
    if (p.y  <= 250 || p.y  >= 350) // ball came from above 
    {
      v.y = -v.y;
    } 
    if (p.x <= 250 || p.x >= 450) // ball came from sides
    {
      v.x = -v.x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if this helped you, otherwise I might be able to help you out a bit more.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what i needed, and it even works for any given velocity. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, i have a new problem with this program. If you could help that would be great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641844/ball-gets-stuck-on-corners-for-rectangle-collision

Comment: Just read your other question, will get back to it after the weekend.