# How to make the ball roll smoothly off the corner?

Tags: java, processing, collision-detection, collision

In this program, the rectangle should block the ball when the mouse is on the opposite side. When the ball and the mouse are on adjacent sides, the ball should roll off the corner. The problem is that this doesn't happens, the ball is stucked on the corner. Here is the complete program:

```
PVector p = new PVector(100, 100); //position
PVector v = new PVector(0, 0); // velocity

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
  frameRate(120);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  rect(250, 250, 200, 100);
  ellipse(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
  v.setMag(2.5);
  p.add(v);

  if (p.x + 10 >= 250 && p.x - 10 <= 450 && p.y + 10 >= 250 && p.y - 10 <= 350) // ball is inside box
  {
    if (p.y  <= 250 || p.y  >= 350) // ball came from above 
    {
      v.y = -v.y;
    } 
    if (p.x <= 250 || p.x >= 450) // ball came from sides
    {
      v.x = -v.x;
    }
  } 
  else // move ball
  { 
    PVector dir = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    v = PVector.sub(dir, p);
  }
}
```

I tried to fix this by checking if a corner has been hit but the ball still gets stuck on the corner.

```
PVector p = new PVector(100, 100); // Pisition
PVector v = new PVector(0, 0); // Velocity

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
  frameRate(120);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  rect(250, 250, 200, 100);
  ellipse(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
  v.setMag(2.5);
  p.add(v);

  if (dist(p.x, p.y, 250, 250)<10) // corner has been hit
  {
    p = new PVector(239, 239); // move ball away from corner
  } 
  else if (dist(p.x, p.y, 450, 250)<10)
  {
    p = new PVector(461, 239);
  } 
  else if (dist(p.x, p.y, 450, 350)<10)
  {
    p = new PVector(461, 361);
  } 
  else if (dist(p.x, p.y, 250, 350)<10)
  {
    p = new PVector(239, 361);
  } 
  else if (p.x + 10 >= 250 && p.x - 10 <= 450 && p.y + 10 >= 250 && p.y - 10 <= 350) // ball is inside box
  {
    if (p.y  <= 250 || p.y  >= 350) // ball came from above 
    {
      v.y = -v.y;
    } 
    if (p.x <= 250 || p.x >= 450) // ball came from sides
    {
      v.x = -v.x;
    }
  } 
  else // move ball towards mouse
  { 
    PVector dir = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    v = PVector.sub(dir, p);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the ball roll smoothly off the corner? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Some screenshots would be useful to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: Cool game mechanism, btw, was it original?

Comment: Hi, the code i pasted is the whole program so you can run it and see how the ball gets trapped on the corner. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't see what's so cool about it XD. What do you mean by original? Did i make this myself? Yes, with the help of someone in my previous post.

Comment: @Saposhiente Oops, sorry. I forgot i put java in the tags so i assumed you use processing.

Comment: @Obama I liked the catching the ball and paddle movement in x and y. If a little gravity and wind or such added, could be neat. Of course, I haven't run the program, so maybe I'm not thinking about it right. Oh I just realized that the rectangle is static, d'oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your sketch in order to solve your problem. The trick is to add a little gap at each corner such that the ball can cross the right angle.

```
PVector p = new PVector(100, 100); //Position
PVector v = new PVector(0, 0);     //Velocity
PVector dir;                       //Direction
int sizeX = 600, sizeY = 600;      //Window size
int rectX = 250, rectY = 250;      //Rectangle position
int rectW = 200, rectH = 100;      //Rectangle size
int ballR = 10;                    //Ball radius
int gap = 2;                       //Corner gap

void setup(){
  size(sizeX, sizeY);
  frameRate(120);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  rect(rectX, rectY, rectW, rectH);
  dir = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  v = PVector.sub(dir, p);
  if((v.x>0 && p.x+ballR > rectX         && p.x+ballR < rectX + rectW &&
               p.y+ballR > rectY + gap   && p.y-ballR < rectY + rectH - gap)
   ||(v.x<0 && p.x-ballR < rectX + rectW && p.x-ballR > rectX &&
               p.y+ballR > rectY + gap   && p.y-ballR < rectY + rectH - gap)){
      v.x = -v.x;
  } 
  if((v.y>0 && p.y+ballR > rectY         && p.y+ballR < rectY + rectH && 
               p.x+ballR > rectX + gap   && p.x-ballR < rectX + rectW - gap)
   ||(v.y<0 && p.y-ballR < rectY + rectH && p.y-ballR > rectY &&
               p.x+ballR > rectX + gap   && p.x-ballR < rectX + rectW - gap)){
      v.y = -v.y;
  }
  v.setMag(2.5);
  p.add(v);
  ellipse(p.x, p.y, 2*ballR, 2*ballR);
}
```